# Change data type in specific element array in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array based query into MySQL.
If the array that come like this:

```
array (size=6)
0 => 
 array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'Login' (length=5)
  'y' => string '1' (length=1)
1 => 
 array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'Printer' (length=7)
  'y' => string '2' (length=1)
2 => 
 array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'Monitor' (length=7)
  'y' => string '0' (length=1)
3 => 
 array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'Computer' (length=8)
  'y' => string '0' (length=1)
4 => 
 array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'Network' (length=7)
  'y' => string '0' (length=1)
5 => 
  array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'Lain Lain' (length=9)
  'y' => string '0' (length=1)
```

How can I make all key 'y' as integer ?

Comment: cast it to an integer when you need to use it as an integer `$z = (int)$array[0]['y'] + 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use array_map to handle all elements in array

```
$arr = [
  ['x' => 'str', 'y' => '1'],
  ['x' => 'str', 'y' => '2'],
  ['x' => 'str', 'y' => '3']
];


print_r(array_map(function($el) {
  $el['y'] = intval($el['y']);
  return $el;
}, $arr));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate over the array and see if `y` holds a numeric value and if it does, cast it as an integer:

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (is_numeric($item['y'])) {
        $item['y'] = intval($item['y']);
    }
}
```

See a working example here: https://3v4l.org/ABDof

Answer (score -1):

With `foreach`:

```
 foreach($myArray as $k=>$v){ //iterate in each array
      $myArray[$k]['y'] = intval($myArray[$k]['y']); //re-set value type
    }
```

**[Example](http://rextester.com/IXRP51355)**